# Add all the same element from different array object

Tags: javascript

I need to add the same elements of the different objects and return `final volumn{ mono: color:}`. See the code below:

```
//function to add different objects
   function addMonoColorVolumn(objects) {
     var volumn = {
       mono: [],
       color: []
     };
     var mono = 0,
       color = 0;

     function addValusCB(obj) {
       if (obj.monoTotal) {
         mono += obj.monoTotal;
         volumn.mono.push(mono);
       }
       if (obj.colorTotal) {
         color += obj.colorTotal;
         volumn.color.push(color);
       }
     }
     if (objects.length) {
       //if objects length is more then 0 than call the callback fn.
       objects.forEach(addValusCB);
     }
     return volumn;
   }


   function main() {
     var testObjects = [{
       monoTotal: 100,
       colorTotal: 200
     }, {
       monoTotal: 100,
       colorTotal: 200
     }, {
       monoTotal: 100,
       colorTotal: 200
     }];
     console.log(testObjects);
     console.log(addMonoColorVolumn(testObjects)) //output should be object{color:1200,mono:600}
   }
   main();
```

I am new in javascript please guide me to resolve this problem. Here is my fiddle [Running fiddel](https://jsfiddle.net/mansu1101/op2rsv0b/).

Comment: *output should be object{color:1200,mono:600}* - it can't be so with your current input. It's `{color:600,mono:300}` now

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and sum the properties, you need.

```js
var testObjects = [{ monoTotal: 100, colorTotal: 200 }, { monoTotal: 100, colorTotal: 200 }, { monoTotal: 100, colorTotal: 200 }],
    sum = testObjects.reduce(function (r, o) {
        ['mono', 'color'].forEach(function (k) {
            r[k] = (r[k] || 0) + o[k + 'Total'];
        });
        return r;
    }, {});

console.log(sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, instead reduce, you can slightly modify your code, like this:

```
   //function to add different objects
   function addMonoColorVolumn(objects) {
     var volumn = {
       mono: 0,
       color: 0
     };
     var mono = 0,
       color = 0;

     function addValusCB(obj) {
       if (obj.monoTotal) {
         mono += obj.monoTotal;
        volumn.mono=mono;
       }
       if (obj.colorTotal) {
         color += obj.colorTotal;
         volumn.color=color;
       }
     }
     if (objects.length) {
       //if objects length is more then 0 than call the callback fn.
       objects.forEach(addValusCB);
     }
     return volumn;
   }


   function test() {
     var testObjects = [{
       monoTotal: 100,
       colorTotal: 200
     }, {
       monoTotal: 100,
       colorTotal: 200
     }, {
       monoTotal: 100,
       colorTotal: 200
     }];
     console.log(testObjects);
     console.log(addMonoColorVolumn(testObjects)) //output should be object{color:1200,mono:600}
   }
   test();
```

```js
//function to add different objects
   function addMonoColorVolumn(objects) {
     var volumn = {
       mono: 0,
       color: 0
     };
     var mono = 0,
       color = 0;

     function addValusCB(obj) {
       if (obj.monoTotal) {
         mono += obj.monoTotal;
        volumn.mono=mono;
       }
       if (obj.colorTotal) {
         color += obj.colorTotal;
         volumn.color=color;
       }
     }
     if (objects.length) {
       //if objects length is more then 0 than call the callback fn.
       objects.forEach(addValusCB);
     }
     return volumn;
   }


   function test() {
     var testObjects = [{
       monoTotal: 100,
       colorTotal: 200
     }, {
       monoTotal: 100,
       colorTotal: 200
     }, {
       monoTotal: 100,
       colorTotal: 200
     }];
    // console.log(testObjects);
     console.log(addMonoColorVolumn(testObjects)) //output should be object{color:1200,mono:600}
   }
   test();
```

Comment: Thank you sinisake.